# Changing Delphi Thread Size on linecode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Here's my problem:

My current threads are created by default with 1024kb, when I normally need less than 50kb.
Is there a way to parametrize its size by coding? I could only find a way to change it via menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify the stack size if you use `BeginThread`, with the appropriate CreationFlags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify stack size using `TThread`. `TThread`'s thread creating code path leads to `CreateThread` API to be called to use the default stack size for the executable. This is by default 1MB for a Delphi executable (as you have noted). Although you can modify this value <sup>(*)</sup> through linker options ([maximum stack size](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Linking)), or through the corresponding [compiler directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Memory_allocation_sizes_%28Delphi%29), that will have an effect on all threads that use default stack in the application (main, 3rd party TThread, ...).

If you can do without `TThread`, you can use the [`BeginThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.BeginThread) RTL function to have the `StackSize` you pass it to be used when you include `STACK_SIZE_IS_A_RESERVATION` in `CreationFlags`.

<sub>(*) The value that will be reserved for thread stack, [Te Waka o Pascal](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/) has an [article](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/1297) showing effects of using different values.</sub>